# API Integration User - why is modify all necessary to create cases assigned to users (not queues)?

Tags: integration, case, permission-sets

When using an integration user to create a Case via standard APIs, I was only successful when the OwnerId was left blank or set to a queueId.

When I tried to set OwnerId to a userId I got the following error.

```
[
    {
        "message": "insufficient access rights on cross-reference id",
        "errorCode": "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY",
        "fields": []
    }
]
```

The only way to resolve this was to modify the Integration User's Case permission set to "Modify all" instead of just Read, Create, Edit and View All? **Why is this necessary?** Aiming for the Principle of Least Privilege access, is there a way to get around granting  the "Modify All" for cases?

Comment: Did you assign permission Transfer Record?

Comment: @cropredy I've tried creating a Case and setting the OwnerId with a simple Read/Create permission on the integration user and I got the same error. Added Transfer Record permission and I got a success. The question is though why I need this permission for Case, but not Account for example? I was able to create an Account via REST API with Read/Create without Transfer Record permission and it worked.

Comment: Speculation -- cases run through assignment rules (or at least the option exists to run them through assignment rules). There aren't assignment rules for Accounts.  It is also possible (untested) that if your Account had a flow or trigger that changed ownership, that the REST would fail without Transfer Records permission.

Comment: Thanks @cropredy, adding that permission fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First of all, you are to be commended for wanting to avoid using the  `Modify All` permission (or the even deadlier `Modify All Data` permission.*

The solution to this is to add

- `Transfer Record` permission to the Permission Set assigned to the API user

Note that in the context of a running transaction, especially for Cases, the initial Case owner can change (i.e. Case Assignment Rules). Hence, Transfer Record permission is required.